# Creating a xcodeproject from app folder?

Tags: ios

I have .app folder. I am able to install and run the app on simulator.

However I also need the associated .KIFtests on this app. The only way I am able to run KIF test is by using xcodebuild command

eg:

/usr/bin/xcodebuild test \
-scheme myTestScheme \
-project "My.xcodeproj" \
-configuration Debug \
-destination name="${DEVICE_NAME}"

So for my case when I have just the .app folder, how do I generate the .xcodeproj for running KIF tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The .app folder is the product of compiling an iOS or Mac app target.
You can't decompile the application and expect to build the Xcode project. There are hundreds of different build settings that wouldn't be able to set properly not to mention it is entirely possible that your .app folder was never created in Xcode.

TL; DR;
You can't.